# Using multiple processer to run the shell script

Tags: shell, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

Shell :

```
for a in `ls -1 *.pdb`; do ./fud --pdb=$a --command=run --state=-CRYSTAL --element=ion ; done 

cat //home/*.fxout  >> results.out

fgrep -v 1 results.out > new.out
```

Comment: elaborate what exact command should be run in parallel?

Comment: I just need this shell script to run using multiple cores

Comment: Maybe you could consider user utility `parallel`

Comment: Beware of [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). What does your script do if a `.pdb` file has a space or newline in the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel ./fud —pdb={} —command=run —state=-CRYSTAL —element=ion ::: *.pdb
```

There’s a great tutorial [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try xargs (-P specifies number of parallel processes to run):

```
ls -1 *.pdb | xargs -I {} -P8 ./fud --pdb={} --rest-of-switches > result.out
```